# Prolog query in python program not returning correct answers

Tags: python, swi-prolog

I am making an expert system in python having a GUI. For that, I have integreted swi-prolog in python using the pyswip library. In the GUI, user selects several values from drop downs (OptionMenu in python). When the variables holding these selected values are passed into the prolog query, " [] " is returned. 
However, if instead of the variables, the values(symptoms in this case) are hard coded into the prolog query below, it works fine.

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
from pyswip import *


sympList=['--Select Symptom--','headache','sneezing','runny_nose','sore_throat','fever','chills','bodyache','abdominal_pain','loss_of_appetite','skin_rash','conjunctivitus','sweating','vomitting','diarrhea']
class DPDP:
def __init__(self, master):

    frame = Frame(master)
    frame.grid()



    #---------medical symbol pic------------------------
    path1 = "Capture.png"
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(path1))
    panel = Label(root, image=img)
    panel.photo = img
    panel.place(x=20,y=20,width=140,height=130)

    #----------page title-----------------------------------
    mainHeading=Label(master,text="Disease Prediction & Drug Prescribtion ", font=('Verdana 20'), bg='#44689E')
    mainHeading.grid(padx=200,pady=60)

    #----------symptoms selection---------------------------------------------------

    #-------Symptom1-------------------------
    symp1=Label(root,text="1st Symptom", font=('Verdana 15'),bg='#44689E')
    symp1.place(x=20,y=200)



    self.selSymp1=StringVar()
    self.selSymp1.set(sympList[0])

    sympDropDown1=OptionMenu(root,self.selSymp1,*sympList)
    sympDropDown1.place(x=180,y=200)


    #-------Symptom2-------------------------

    self.symp2=Label(root,text="2nd Symptom", font=('Verdana 15'),bg='#44689E')
    self.symp2.place(x=20,y=300)


    self.selSymp2=StringVar()
    self.selSymp2.set(sympList[0])

    sympDropDown2=OptionMenu(root,self.selSymp2,*sympList)
    sympDropDown2.place(x=180,y=300)

    #-------Symptom3-------------------------

    self.symp3=Label(root,text="3rd Symptom", font=('Verdana 15'),bg='#44689E')
    self.symp3.place(x=20,y=400)


    self.selSymp3=StringVar()
    self.selSymp3.set(sympList[0])

    sympDropDown3=OptionMenu(root,self.selSymp3,*sympList)
    sympDropDown3.place(x=180,y=400)

    #-------Symptom4-------------------------

    symp4=Label(root,text="4th Symptom", font=('Verdana 15'),bg='#44689E')
    symp4.place(x=20,y=500)


    self.selSymp4=StringVar()
    self.selSymp4.set(sympList[0])

    sympDropDown4=OptionMenu(root,self.selSymp4,*sympList)
    sympDropDown4.place(x=180,y=500)

    bt=Button(frame,text="click",width=5,
    command=lambda:queryGenerator(self.selSy 
    mp1.get(),self.selSymp2.get(),self.selSymp3.get(),
    self.selSymp4.get()))
    bt.grid(row=4,column=5)




def queryGenerator(s1,s2,s3,s4):

    print(s1,s2,s3,s4) #this prints the values that are chosen,correctly
    prolog = Prolog()
    prolog.consult('kb.pl')        

    q=list(prolog.query("telldisease(X,s1,s2,s3,s4).")) #prolog query
   # for e in q[0].values():
   # print("You have " + e)
   # break
    print(q)


root = Tk()
root.geometry("820x600")
root.resizable(0,0)
root.config(bg='#44689E')
app= DPDP(root)
root.title("DPDP")
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When the variables holding these selected values are passed into the prolog query, " [] " is returned. However, if instead of the variables, the values(symptoms in this case) are hard coded into the prolog query below, it works fine.

You are passing the literal query `"telldisease(X,s1,s2,s3,s4)."`, but you want to [*interpolate*](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/string-interpolation) the values of s1, s2, s3 and s4 into the query string; this can be done e. g. with %-formatting:

```
    q = list(prolog.query("telldisease(X,%s,%s,%s,%s)." % (s1, s2, s3, s4)))
```